# segmentation fault (core dumped) pointer struct data type

Tags: c++11, pointers, struct

i am trying to create a tree using struct in C

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
  int data;
  struct node * next, * left, * right;
};

struct node * createtree(int data){
  struct node * kosong = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  kosong->data = data;
  kosong->left = kosong->right = NULL;
  return kosong;
}

void printtree(struct node * tree){
  if(tree == NULL) return;
  printtree(tree->left);
  printf("%d ",tree->data);
  printtree(tree->right);
}

int main(){
  struct node * pohon = NULL;
  pohon = createtree(1);
  pohon->left = createtree(2);
  pohon->right = createtree(3);
  pohon->left->left = createtree(4);
  pohon->left->right = createtree(5);
  printtree(pohon);
}
```

whenever i compile it gets segmentation fault. Then i try to delete the * next pointer and it compiles & run successfully. I know tree does not need the * next pointer , but i dont see why it wont compile just because of another same pointer.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: `struct node * kosong = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` --> `struct node * kosong = malloc(sizeof(struct node));` (Also `next` is uninitialized.)

Comment: 1. doesn't the right format is [struct node * = (char *) malloc(size)] ?

Comment: 2. why next being uninitialized is the cause?

Comment: The format bluepixy mentioned is correct. [Don't cast memory allocation functions in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: i just compiled it and i get segfault

Comment: 1) C does not need to cast.

Comment: Your main problem is to ensure the size of the pointer, not object size.

Comment: [DEMO](http://ideone.com/qlHWrS) this work well.

Comment: im sorry i mean to compile it in c++

Comment: Ah, I understand. It is a common mistake.

Comment: and im confused with deleting 1 pointer solve the segmentation fault

Comment: undefined behavior is undefined. It includes the case that it **seems** to work normally.

Comment: btw i just change the position of * next and * right pointer and it compiles just fine. so weird

Comment: [This question](/questions/45390793) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help you understanding the mistake:

- first line in function createtree(int data):

  ```
  struct node * kosong = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
  ```

  should actually be

  ```
  struct node * kosong = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ```

  Because you are allocating memory for a struct node, not for a pointer to a struct node.

And this is the actual reason for your segfault. I compiled the code with only fixing this mistake and it worked absolutely fine.
Of course you should try initializing all pointers and variables, as doing not might end in **undefined behaviour**, which can be anything, just like segmentation faults.

Comment: after reading your comment i tried to print the result of sizeof(struct node) = 32 and sizeof(struct node*) = 8. After i deleted 1 pointer,  sizeof(struct node) become 24, and it works just fine. Does this still count as undefined behavior because i allocate  less than the required memory (i allocate with the size of pointer for a struct node) ?

Comment: Correct. Since you allocate less memory than needed by your struct, there's no telling if you are going to overwrite some data in your heap which leads to your segfault.